# Can I purchase an item in Brick-Force permanently?

Tags: brick-force

Is there a way to buy items in Brick-Force permanently? It seems I can buy for increments of 7 days, but I'd like a permanent solution.

Or is it like Gunbound with only a "rental" scheme for items?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

Following an update, the rental system for weapons has been removed and they can only be purchased permanently now. You'll still need to repair them, though. Specifics on that can be found [in this post](http://www.brick-force.com/forum/showthread.php?p=68235).

Clothing and accessories are still on a rental system, but can be purchased permanently using Tokens (premium currency that costs real money).